# Is it possible to dereference a reference in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an array I'm using as a stack to store a path through a tree. Each element points to a node in the tree and I want to pop the last element off and then set the object referred to by that element to null.

Basically:

```
$node = array_pop($path);
*$node = null;
```

assuming that PHP had a '*' operator as C-ish languages do. Right now I have the ugly solution of starting at the parent node and remembering which child I took and then setting that to null as in:

```
if($goLeft) {
    $parent->left = null;
} else {
    $parent->right = null;
}
```

I say this is ugly because the array containing the path is created by a public function in my tree class. I'd like to expose the ability to work directly on the nodes in a path through the tree without exposing an implementation detail that addresses an idiosyncrasy (feature?) in PHP. ATM I need to include a boolean in the return value ($goLeft in this case) just so I can workaround an inability to dereference a reference.

This is the second time I've encountered this problem, so if anyone knows a way I can do something similar to the first block of code please share!

(EDIT)

After experimenting with many permutations of &'s and arrays, it turns out that the basic problem was that I had misinterpreted the reason for an error I was getting.

I tried

```
$a = ($x > $y) ? &$foo[$bar] : $blah;
```

and got " syntax error, unexpected '&' ". I interpreted this to mean that the problem was using the &-operator on `$foo[$bar]`. It actually turns out that the culprit is the ?-operator, as

```
if($x > $y) {
    $a = &$foo[$bar];
} else {
    $a = null;
}
```

works perfectly fine. I thus went on a wild goose chase looking for a workaround for a problem that didn't exist. As long as I don't break the chain of &'s, PHP does what I want, which is to operate on the object referred to by a variable (not the variable itself). Example

```
$a1 = new SomeClass;
$a2 = &$a1;
$a3 = &$a2;
$a4 = &$a3;

$a4 = 42;    // This actually sets $a1 to 42
var_dump($a1); // Emits 42
```

What messed me up is that I thought objects are passed around by reference anyway (this is wrong), so I didn't think the & was necessary if the expression resolved to an object. I mean:

```
class A {
    public $b;
}

class B {}

$a = new A;
$a->b = new B; 

$c1 = $a->b; 
$c2 = &$a->b;

$c1 = 42; // Merely assigns 42 to $c1
$c2 = 42; // Assigns 42 to $a->b
```

It turns out that this exact issue is addressed at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php. Wish that had sunk in the first time I read it!

Comment: I am not sure, this is what you want, but you can use `unset($parent->left);` instead of `$parent->left = null;`

Comment: @PLB: I think you mean `unset`, not `unlink`.

Comment: @Rocket Sure, I do. I am very tired.

Comment: @PLB: Thanks, but the code in the second block works fine as it is. As a matter of fact I need to keep the variable names around in the parent node, so unset won't do. I'm looking for something that works like the first block of code. But thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Would **not** assigning it to a variable in the first place achieve the goal? e.g. just `array_pop($path)` - as far as I can tell, what you're trying to achieve is freeing up memory - but as PHP is a garbage collected language, variables are cleaned up when the function `return`s (or the script ends).

Comment: I don't get whqt you're trying to do. what would you expect (if it existed) *$node = null to do? maybe you could show your tree class to help us understand

Comment: For those who don't understand, `$path` is an array of references (to objects).  He wants to unset the original object via the reference.  `$a=(object)'a';  $b=array($a); $c=array_pop($b); echo $a->scalar; //'a'`  (Yes, that code works: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). He wants to set `$a` to null only using `$c`.

Comment: But... if they're **references** to the objects inside the array `$path[] = &$oObject;` then by popping it off the end of the array **without** assigning it to a variable - doesn't that effectively unset the original object?

Comment: @CD001: No, it doesn't.  http://ideone.com/2aShg

Comment: @Rocket: You got it, this is exactly what I want to do!

Comment: @kahulio: Pretty sure you can't do that.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Comment: @Rocket - Ah... hmmm, yeah you're right thinking about it, this is one I'd actually need to sit down and hammer some code out on to run tests until I figured it out (I refuse to believe it's impossible); by the time I've done that I'm sure someone will have posted the solution... if it turns out to be something as simple as `unset(array_pop($path))` I'd like to know :)

Comment: @CD001 hmmm, are you sure that this works? `array_pop` returns value and at this time you're trying to write something in the return value. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Rocket I think you hit the nail on the head there, it's just not possible. The only way to do it would be to implement a `destroy()` method of the tree class and pass the `array_pop()`ed item to it, in which one could loop the objects held in the tree and find the right one with `===`, then unset it. But even then it wouldn't be fool proof, since (AFAIK) there is no way to determine whether one has the same instance of an object or just an object with the same exact structure...

Comment: If this isn't homework, it sounds a lot like `\SplDoulblyLinkedList` meets your needs

Comment: @CoryCarson: Interesting, think you can show an example?

Comment: @Rocket: damn, thanks for pointing that out. If there were a way to have an object refer to itself, as in `$node->me` this would work too, but so far I haven't found a solution on that front either. Trying to unset the return value from the member function `public function getMe() { return $this; }` doesn't work and gives the error "Can't use method return value in write context."

Comment: @kahulio: Unset only works on variables.  When you return from a function, there's no "variable" to unset.

Comment: @CoryCarson: actually, it is homework of sorts. As an exercise in learning PHP I'm going through a book on data structures and algorithms and implementing these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very interesting question! I may have found a workaround: if you populate the array with object references, with the `&` operator, you can destroy the original object by setting that array value to `NULL`. You have to operate on the array directly, instead of using a variable returned by `array_pop`. After that you can pop the array to free that position (that would then contain a `NULL` value).

This is what I mean (based on Rocket's code):

```
$a=(object)'a';
$b=array(&$a);
$b[0] = NULL;
// array still contains an element
array_pop($b);
// now array is empty
var_dump($a); // NULL
```

http://codepad.org/3D7Lphde

Comment: @bfavaretto: You solved it! Awesome, and so simple! I'm stoked that there's a prettier way to do what I wanted. Thanks for all the help guys, Stack Overflow rules!

Comment: Heh - it was almost as simple as I thought it should be... knew someone would get there before I got home :D The trick is using references in the array.

Comment: @CD001, yeah, when I saw your comment on the question I thought the same.

Comment: This depends on the array being `0` indexed at all times

Comment: @tandu, there are [ways to get the last index](http://codepad.org/9baHdteG) if it's not zero-indexed. But since OP is talking about a stack, that probably won't be necessary.

Comment: @bfavaretto [It is possible](http://codepad.org/21Uw7Kus) to roll your own `array_pop()`-like function that works as well :-D

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could remember where I read this, but PHP works by maintaining a counter of references to a given object.  You have some object (e.g. a `Tree`) that has a reference to some nodes.  When you use `array_pop`, a reference to the node object is returned (i.e. an additional reference is created), but the original reference still exists.  When you `unset` the popped reference, that is destroyed but the original object is not destroyed because `Tree` still has that reference.  The only way to free the memory of that object is to have `Tree` destroy it personally (which seems to be what you're doing in the second code block).

PHP does not seem to have any method for forcing memory deallocation or garbage collection, so unless you carefully handle your references, you're stuck.

**This is not possible**

P.S. I'm still really confused about what you're trying to do.  Rocket's explanation helps, but what is `$path`, and how does it relate to the second block?

Comment: I think my original question was overly specific. It really doesn't even matter that I'm working with a stack, or trying to set something null. I need to get better at explaining myself.

Let's say I have a variable which holds a reference to something - an object, another variable, it doesn't matter. Example:

`$a = &$b;`

Now I want to perform an operation on the thing referred to by `$a`, which in this case is `$b`. Maybe I want to set `$b` to null, the string "alice", or to another object. Doesn't matter. Anyway, this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @kahulio this is a bit hard to explain.  Basically, `$a = &$b` creates a symbol table alias from `$a` to `$b`.  That is, anything you do to `$a` affects `$b` directly.  If `$b` is an object, then `$a = $b` copies the object reference from `$b` to `$a`.  Operations on object `$a` have the same effect as on object `$b`, but it is a separate symbol table entry.  If you write to `$a` (`$a = 'blah';`) it does not affect `$b` at all.  `array_pop` does *not* return a reference (alias) and cannot, so writing to its return value does not affect the original object in any way, nor can it.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't assign the `array_pop()` return value.

```
php > $test = array(1, 2, 3);
php > $test2 = array(0 => &$test[0], 1 => &$test[1], 2 => &$test[2]);
php > array_pop($test2);
php > var_dump($test);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &int(1)
  [1]=>
  &int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
php > var_dump($test2);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  &int(1)
  [1]=>
  &int(2)
}
```

Comment: Not quite.  What he wants is for the "original" object to be unset (`$test[2]`).  Why does the return value of `array_pop` matter?  You're modifying `$test2` either way.

Comment: Well ... that's a hard one to get from the description. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$array = array(&$one, &$two);

// magic
end($array);
$array[key($array)] = NULL;

var_dump($two);
// NULL
```

Reference in php allows you to change object.